# Automatic riding mower with reversed transmission

Tags: transmission

I have a30in craftsman riding lawn mower I just purchased off a guy.  I got it running but,  when I push the lever forward it goes backwards and pulling the lever backwards it goes forwards.  What is or could be the problem?

Comment: Is the drive belt meant to have a twist in it?

Comment: It is a 2 stroke or 4 stroke engine? Some 2 strokes will run in either direction depending which way you spin them to start. I used to know a guy with a bike that could be started "in reverse" by putting it in gear, then knocking it off the stand backwards to turn it over the "wrong way", and immediately pulling the clutch so it didn't stall.